# Angular 2 - cant navigate to route directly using the URL

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I've set up some routing in my angular 2 project.  This has never been a problem for me in the past but I'm having difficulty with this newer version of angular.

If I click links to the routes I have no problems.  However if I go to any route other than my root `(/)` my app will be stuck on a loading screen.  Every time i try to go to `/login` through the url I get stuck..

relevant files

**app.routes.ts**

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component'
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component'

import { AuthGuard } from './auth-guard.service'

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
]

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    StoreModule.provideStore({user})
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    AuthService,
    appRoutingProviders
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="app/assets/img/irs-logo.png" alt="irs">
</div>  
  <nav>
    <a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">login</a>
    <a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active">dashboard</a>
  </nav>

<div id="body" class="container body">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

is there anything else i could be missing here?

my components are pretty much empty shells at this stage

Comment: does your Authguard service have something to do with this? try removing the logic to see if its affecting routing some how.

Comment: try to add { path: '**', redirectTo: ''} in very end of appRoutes and than try to go to path other than root. Check if this redirect you to main or will stuck, also check with login and look what happen

Comment: @ulou i tried that and no change

Comment: @Bean0341 I commented out all my auth guard code and no change =/

Comment: Do you can create plunker or something like that?

Comment: I don't know how to make plunker match my project settings exactly? It looks like the version of angular plunker is using is outdated...  sorry I've never used it before.

Comment: i created a new project and im having the same problem.  here is my project zipped

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4kzFbLmJr19dWcwMjRVZ0M2cTA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing I was doing worked.

I followed the steps here:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

seems to have fixed everything

Comment: Even still updating Angular cli would have to point out what is the issue ! Updating the cli alone cannot fix it ! There has to be a typescript config that has to be changed in the project.

Answer (score -1):

if you're using the final release, this is how it will be:

`[routerLink]="['login']"`

(notice also there is no leading `/`)